# Is it acceptable to ask someone for help revising your paper?

Tags: publications, writing, research-undergraduate

I am an undergraduate and I was wondering if it was appropriate to ask someone (who isn't an author) to help revise the draft of a conference paper that I am writing.

I am new to writing and this would be helpful to get input from as many people as possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends what you are asking them to do.

You should definitely ask someone (maybe multiple someone's) to read your paper, give you comments about what was confusing/particularly clear/incomplete as well as suggestions on how to improve the paper. (In fact I would recommend this to anyone writing a paper at any stage, not just an undergraduate.) This might be done by your advisor if you have one, and you should thank them in the Acknowledgements section for their help (and personally too, expressing gratitude is always good!)

You should not ask someone a non-co-author to actually edit your paper and make changes to it themselves. Any actual editing should be done by you or your co-authors, otherwise plagiarism becomes a concern.

Comment: +1: This is a better expression of what I was getting at in my other comment.

Comment: Thanks - I have a few professors that I am good friends with and they said that they would be happy to look it over.

Answer (score 14):

It is not just acceptable -- it is to be recommended!

It is generally a good idea to have people read your work before it is submitted, or in your case, presented at a conference.

Having someone from outside your specific research area read your paper is particularly good. Even if your reader isn't familiar with the fine details, they should still be able to follow your general argument from background, through your method, results, analysis and finally to your conclusions.

Approach your intended reader and very politely ask if they would read your work. Make sure you are clear about what you want from them. If it is a colleague who is familiar with your work, you can perhaps ask and expect questions or comments on the finer points of your work. For someone outside your particular field, you can expect general comments on structure or questions on the broader aspects of your work.

At a previous institution, we were all expected to hand our draft papers around for two internal reviewers to read, neither of whom were to be from the particular research field on which the paper was written. This was a very valuable exercise.

Comment: I totally agree that it's great to get other people to read your papers and make comments on them.  If that's what "help revise" means, then sure.  If it means that the other person is actually doing the rewriting...that is less clearly good.